# I have network error in fetch api.How can I solve this error?

Tags: node.js

This is my backend api ,

```
app.get('/google',passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile','email'] }));
```

This is my frontend fetch,

```
 axios(`http://localhost:3333/google`, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      mode: "cors",
      credentials: "same-origin",
    })
      .then((d) => d.text())
      .catch((e) => console.log({ e }));
```

Comment: *How can I solve this error* => What error ?

Comment: return error in front end like network error in fetch function.